# How to connect Java App with Virtual Machine and Run bash scripts

Tags: java, bash, sockets, connection, virtual-machine

I need to connect my Java Application to Virtual Machine. After connecting I need to send String saved in my code to bash script, execute it, and then get the output of the script (it comes out in csv file), and then I need to compare it to another csv file that's in the code. I know how to compare it, but I don't know how to connect to Virtual Machine.
I would be very happy if someone could help.

Basicly, I don't know how to connect to Virtual Machine with my Java App, any comment will help, should I use socket? If so, where to start?

Well, i tried to connect to VM with running proces but that didn't worked out. It's a corporate Vitrual Machine, that runs opperations for clients.

Comment: What does "i tried to connect to VM with running proces" mean? What process? How did you try to connect?

Comment: I was trying to connect to putty that was connected to VM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.